# replace img src in textarea using jquery referencing a class

Tags: jquery, image, class, textarea, src

I'm having trouble replacing the image source in a text area referencing a class.

Here's the html:

```
<textarea cols="100" rows="20" class="editor">
    <a href="http://www.amazon.com">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="replace image source in textbox" />
    </a>
</textarea>
```

Here's the jquery I've tried:

```
$(".editor img").attr("src", "image2.jpg");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it that way, since a textarea is a dom element itself.

You can instead put your textarea's content into an hidden div, replace your image, take the new div's content and place it into the original textarea.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/f4dbtjnL/

```
$("textarea").after("<div class='hidden'></div>");
$(".hidden").html($("textarea").val());

$(".hidden img").attr("src", "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1");

$("textarea").val( $(".hidden").remove().html() );
```